# Quartz.net - F# Keymatcher

Tags: f#, quartz.net, c#-to-f#, quartz.net-2.0

I am guessing this is probably going to be a fairly simple question and apologize that I haven't been able to find the answer for this one.

When working with Quartz.net in C# if you are using a job listener, you usually use something like this line of code :

```
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(myJobListener, KeyMatcher.keyEquals(myJobKey));
```

You could also use :

```
scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(myJobListener);
```

But then the JobListener would be paying attention to any job rather than a specified one.

When working in F#, I can successfully create and add a JobListener but KeyMatcher doesn't seem to be recognized.  I'm wondering if it uses a different name or if I am missing an import declaration.  Here are the two import declarations I am currently using related to Quartz :

```
open Quartz
open Quartz.Impl
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: I know nothing about Quartz.net but surely you just have to look for the right namespace for `KeyMatcher

Comment: From http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/b3801021-b3f7-8522-7c87-9224cd581ff3.htm : How about Quartz.Impl.KeyMatchers?

Comment: Quartz.Impl.KeyMatchers does not work, but Quartz.Impl.Matchers does.  Thanks.